# Чем mock отличается от stub в phunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

Mock - используется для проверки состояния объекта, например, чтобы проверить был ли вызван метод

Stub - используется для возвращения ложных (тестовых) данных

Вопрос: **следующий код это mock или stub?** Мы проверяем вызов метода, но в то же время возвращаем ложные данные

```
$observer = $this->createMock(Observer::class);

        $observer->expects($this->once())
        ->method('abstractMethod')
        ->will($this->returnValue('wow'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю все-таки мок, поскольку имитирует вызов метода. И имитирует возврат значения из метода, так как без этого имитация (и проверка) будет неполной